# MySQL - if count in select subquery is null change to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have following query:

```
select `jobs`.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(user_jobs_application.id) as count FROM user_jobs_application
join job_shifts on job_shifts.id = user_jobs_application.job_shift_id
where job_shifts.jobs_id = jobs.id
and user_jobs_application.status = 1
group by user_jobs_application.users_id
) as entries
from `jobs` where `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc limit 25 offset 0
```

The subquery in **select** will give **null** instead of 0. Can I change this so if the value is **null** it will show 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `group by` clause from the subquery should be sufficient. It is not needed anyway, since it groups on the column you are filtering on (and it it was needed, then I would mean the subquery may return more than one row, which would generate a runtime error).

```
select 
    j.*, 
    (
        select count(*) as count 
        from user_jobs_application uja
        join job_shifts js on js.id = uja.job_shift_id
        where js.jobs_id = j.id and uja.status = 1
    ) as entries
from jobs j
where j.deleted_at is null 
order by id desc limit 25 offset 0
```

Other changes to your query:

- presumably, `user_jobs_application(id)` is not nullable; if so, `count(*)` is good enough, and is more efficient than `count(user_jobs_application.id)`
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation :)